# How to easily put all echo statements in a shell script into a log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script which does echo for some important places in the logic. Every time I do an echo I apeend the log to a log file by doing a `>> /some/location/my_logtxt`.

The logic looks like below

```
ret=123
echo Something happened $ret >> /some/location/my_logtxt

// some logic 
echo Something else happened $ret >> /some/location/my_logtxt

// some more logic 

echo Something else happened again $ret >> /some/location/my_logtxt
```

**Question:**
Isnt there a single statement which can state all the echo statement logs go into the following file instead of doing this `>> /some/location/my_logtxt` for every `echo`?

Comment: What are you trying to save here? reduce the number of lines? Probably define a function and pass the argument as the string to write to the file and call the function with arguments?

Comment: ok . creating a method should work as well. But I wanted to know is there is a standard way in shell scripting to deal with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *all* output to go to the log file, you can use `exec` to redirect:

```
exec >> "$logfile"
```

You might wish to redirect stderr, too: `2>&1`.

---

If you want just your `echo` commands to be redirected, you can connect an unused stream (greater than 2) for that:

```
exec 3>> "$logfile"

ret=123
echo "Something happened $ret" >&3

# some logic 
echo "Something else happened $ret" >&3
```

---

Note that these approaches no longer re-open the log for every write - if you rename the log file, output will continue to go to it, whereas in the original, subsequent output would end up in a new file with the old name.

Answer (score 1):

You can scope your stuff in a subshell and redirect the subshell's output:

```
(
    ret=123
    echo Something happened "$ret"
    // some logic 
    echo Something else happened "$ret"
    // some more logic 
    echo Something else happened again "$ret"
) >> /some/location/my_logtxt
```

If you just want to affect your `echo` statements, I propose to use a `myecho` statement instead:

```
myecho() {
    echo "$@" >> /some/location/my_logtxt
}

ret=123
myecho Something happened "$ret"
// some logic 
myecho Something else happened "$ret"
// some more logic 
myecho Something else happened again "$ret"
```

(A more fitting name might be something like `log` instead of `myecho`, but I guess you got the point.)

Comment: ah. this is also a nice technique on what I was looking for. Thanks a lot